# Slide show inside of Body Content

Tags: javascript

There are no shortages of options for slide shows in Drupal: views, modules, themes, etc. However, I need an option for ***inside the Body Field***. I'm dreaming of an option that

- Content editors can assemble without manually entering Javascript or CSS in the body or [Code Per Node](https://drupal.org/project/cpn) field
- Accessible to screen readers (Jaws, Voiceover, Orca) by having Aria roles and landmarks in place
- Is a module which, perhaps, employs an input filter.

Does such a solution exist? Is this a time to begin exploring [Polymer](http://www.polymer-project.org/) more deeply?

In all my searches, I've seen blocks and views, but nothing that can be dropped into the Body Field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I'm liking the idea of just building a input filter module ([on github](https://github.com/rgoodie/soc_js_slideshow)).

PHP

```
function _MYMOD_process($text, $filter, $format, $langcode, $cache, $cache_id) {


  preg_match_all("/\[slideshow:(#[\S]+)\]/", $text, $matches);

  // If no match return and be done.
  if (! isset($matches[1])) {
    return $text;
  }

  // gather information
  $text_to_remove   = $matches[0];
  $elementid        = $matches[1];

  // remove filter trigger text
  $text = str_replace($text_to_remove, '', $text);

  // TODO: Inject javascript file
  drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'MYMOD') . '/slider.js', 'file');

// TODO: Start process
drupal_add_js('jQuery(document).ready(function () { var s = new SlideShow("' + $elementid +' "); s.process(); });', 'inline');




  return $text;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
function SlideShow(parentContainerId) {

    this.BEGINNING  = 'Beginning';
    this.END        = 'End of list';
    this.FIRSTINDEX = 0;

    this.length     = jQuery(parentContainerId + ' img').length;
    this.container  = jQuery(parentContainerId);
    this.imgs       = jQuery(parentContainerId + ' img');
    this.index      = this.FIRSTINDEX;
    this.status     = 'beginning';           // beginning, end






    this.moveByIncrement = function(n) {

        // [in|de]crese
        this.index =  this.checkBounds(this.index + n);

        // return child
        return this.returnChild()
    }

   this.moveTo = function(n) {
        this.index = this.checkBounds(n);
        return this.returnChild();
    }

    this.returnChild = function() {
        return this.imgs.eq(this.index);
    }

    this.checkBounds = function(n) {
        // ensure index number is not beyond limits
        if (n < this.FIRSTINDEX) {
            n = this.FIRSTINDEX;
            this.status = this.BEGINNING;
        }
        if (n > this.length) {
            n = this.length;
            this.status = this.END;
        }

        return n;
    }

    this.process = function() {
        jQuery(this.imgs).hide();
        jQuery(this.returnChild()).show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

that's a hard point that i'm also dealing with.

Actually i imagine 2 differents ways to solve this :

- i install the module [paragraph](https://www.drupal.org/project/paragraphs)
  It is pretty anwsome by changing the way a user contribute. But it doesn't allow to add a slideshow in a Body field.
- Creating a plugins for CKEditor that create (a new button) that will add the slideshow HTML in the Body Field.
  This button will be like "Create a table" button, you will decide how many images is needed and you will just add the  to it.
  The HTML is quite simple, for bxSlider (http://bxslider.com/) for Exemple you will need to add this :

> ```
> <div>
>   <ul class="bxslider">
>     <li><img src="/images/pic1.jpg" /></li>
>     <li><img src="/images/pic2.jpg" /></li>
>     <li><img src="/images/pic3.jpg" /></li>
>     <li><img src="/images/pic4.jpg" /></li>
>   </ul>
> </div>
> ```

And for SlidesJS it's :

```
<div id="slides">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/940x528">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/940x528">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/940x528">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/940x528">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/940x528">
</div>
```

I didn't start this plugins yet because i finally decide to use Paragraph but i think this plugins for CKEditor can be a good tool in the futur.

Comment: If you're using Bootstrap as a theme, you can use the [CKEditor Bootstrap](http://drupal.org/project/ckeditor_bootstrap) module that gives you plugins like Carousel, Featurettes, Jumbotrons, etc.